# Derived class instances to share the same base class instance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Say I have a `Proc` class with the following interface:

```
class Proc
{
public:
  void process();
protected:
  virtual void do_process() = 0;
private:
  int m_counter;
};
```

Now, say I have two derived classes that implement `Proc` interface.

```
class DerivedProc1:
  public Proc
{
protected:
  virtual void do_process();
};

class DerivedProc2:
  public Proc
{
protected:
  virtual void do_process();
};
```

Now I generate two derived classes as:

```
Proc* dp1 = new  DerivedProc1();
Proc* dp2 = new  DerivedProc2();
```

#### Question

I would like both `dp1` and `dp2` to **share the same base class instance**.
The reason I need that is because `Proc::m_counter` must be the same in both processor, meaning, changing its value in one processor must be "seen" by the other one. Of course, `Proc::m_counter` is just an example of a variable I'd like share.
what is the standard approach for that issue?

#### Notes

I'm not looking for a quick fix for the issue. meaning:

1. making `Proc::m_counter` `static` is not desired. I still need it to be bound to a specific `Proc` instance.
2. I don't want to hold `m_counter` outside of `Proc` and pass is as a reference to `proc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated it is not possible. The following requirements are mutually contradictory:

- The count is a data member of an instance of `DerivedProc1`, not "outside of `Proc`".
- The count is a data member of an instance of `DerivedProc2`.
- The instance of `DerivedProc1` and the instance of `DerivedProc2` are allocated by separate calls to `new`, that is to say they are different most-derived objects.

Different most-derived objects *cannot* share a data member. The reason is that a most-derived object is defined to occupy its own region of memory. Only subobjects of the same most-derived object can share members.

If you're willing to relax the "store outside" restriction then the solution is "obvious": have each object hold a `shared_ptr` to something with the count in it. Pass the same count-holding object to the constructors of whatever objects you wish to share a count. The only thing making this question difficult is your restriction on where the count is located in memory.

If you're willing to relax the "separate `new` calls" restriction then you could use virtual inheritance and construct both `Proc` objects as base-class subobjects of a single most-derived object:

```
class DerivedProc1 : public virtual Proc { ... };
class DerivedProc2 : public virtual Proc { ... };

class CombinedProc : public DerivedProc1, DerivedProc2 { ... };

CombinedProc *dp0 = new CombinedProc();
DerivedProc1 *dp1 = dp0;
DerivedProc2 *dp2 = dp0;
```

Since none of the classes has a virtual destructor, you must use `dp0` (and not `dp1` or `dp2`) to delete the object. If you give `Proc` a virtual destructor then you could use any one (and only one) of them.

I would not advise using virtual inheritance unless you properly understand it. So, since you're going to have to relax one of the requirements I'd normally say that the standard approach is relaxing the first: store the count in a separate object outside of the two objects.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it recognize and explain why my requirements cannot be fulfilled.

Comment: You can use a reference to `m_count` and need to pass a reference to the constructors.  It is correct that the 'data layout' requirements restrict this.  The 'copy' approach is a nightmare if you are doing asynchronous programming (interrupts, thread, SMP, etc).  I knew of the virtual inheritance and it is a great suggestion. My circumstance is 1. 'camera has stream and registers' .  2 'stream has a usb interface'. 3. 'registers has a usb interface'.  Keeping a single source of truth for the usb information greatly simplifies things.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use inheritance. Instead, give `DerivedProc1` and `DerivedProc1` a member pointer to a `Proc` instance and construct both objects with a pointer to a single `Proc` object.

Something like this:

```
class DerivedProc1
{
protected:
  Proc *proc;
  void do_process(){
     proc->process();
  }
public:
  DerivedProc1(Proc *proc):proc(proc){}
};
```

Probably best to use `std::shared_ptr<Proc>` over raw pointers as derived class members.

Comment: But now I lose my `Proc` interface. I'd still want it to be clear the derived processor must implement specific interface.

Comment: Then make an abstract base class to define the interface. If you want to share data between objects of *different* derived classes, you are going to need to share member variables in any case; so my suggestion is an inevitable part of the solution.

Comment: +1 for the `std::shared_ptr<>` tip; I learn something every day here at SO.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a *base* class with a shared resource, have a base class just for the interface, and then a separate object that is shared between the classes, which contains the counter.

Comment: who will hold that object of shared resources? It seem very natural to leave the resources in `Proc`.

Comment: @idanshmu How about both? Easily solvable with [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: I understand `shared_ptr`. what really bothers me is that based on your suggestion the creator of `Proc` classes needs to know  and create resource class just to overcome a problem in my design.

Comment: @idanshmu: you could write a convenience function that constructs the counter and the two `Proc` objects, and returns pointers or `unique_ptr`s to the `Proc` objects. Then the caller just uses that function to get two related objects.

Answer (score 1):

First, `do_process` must be `virtual` and the `DerivedProcX` needs to derive from `Proc`.

To share the counter you can declare it as `static` and make the base class a template, something like this:

```
class BaseProc {};

template <int n> class Proc : BaseProc
{
    virtual void do_process() = 0;
    static int m_counter;
}

template <int n> class DerivedProc1 : public Proc<n>
{
    void do_process() {}
}

template <int n> class DerivedProc2 : public Proc<n>
{
    void do_process() {}
}

int main()
{
    // dp1 and dp2 share the same counter
    Proc<1>* dp1 = new DerivedProc1<1>;
    Proc<1>* dp2 = new DerivedProc2<1>;

    // dp3 and dp4 share the same counter, but not the same as dp1 and dp2
    BaseProc* dp3 = new DerivedProc1<2>;
    BaseProc* dp4 = new DerivedProc2<2>;
}
```

Of course this solution assumes that you know at compile time what instances will need to share the same counter.

Comment: Hmm, in a question where one of the questioner's requirements *must* be violated you make an interesting choice by in effect only semi-violating the requirement that the counter is part of the objects :-) However, `Proc` is not a class (it's a template), so you can't actually convert all of the pointers the same type `Proc*` like that. You could if you stuck in another base class above `Proc<n>`.

Comment: what bothers me here is the the creator of `Proc` classes needs to pass some "weird number" (the users of those classes have no idea what those number means) just to overcome a problem in my design. I don't want the users of my class to suffer. I'd like to resolve this issue inside `Proc` classes.

Comment: @idanshmu: the users have to do something. There is no way for the derived classes to "know" which instances should share counts and which should not, unless the code that constructs them tells them. It's perfectly normal for code that creates objects to provide the details of any relationships between those objects.

Comment: @SteveJessop you are right. I was asking for some magic trick that can't be done.

Comment: @SteveJessop You are right, I'll edit the answer to fix the base class problem... in two different ways :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider your design.

According to me, you need a hybrid design consisting inheritance as well as composition (like the following).

```
class CounterHolder
{
public:
    int m_counter;
};

class Proc
{
public:
    Proc(CounterHolder *counterHolder)
    {
        m_conterHolder = counterHolder;
    }

    void process();
protected:
    virtual void do_process() = 0;
private:
    CounterHolder *m_counterHolder;
};

class DerivedProc1: public Proc
{
public:
    DerivedProc1(CounterHolder *counterHolder) : Proc(counterHolder);
protected:
    virtual void do_process();
};

class DerivedProc2: public Proc
{
public:
    DerivedProc2(CounterHolder *counterHolder) : Proc(counterHolder);
protected:
    virtual void do_process();
};
```

Now, you have perks of both **inheritance** as well as **shared data** (due to composition)

```
CounterHolder *counterHolder = new CounterHolder();
Proc* dp1 = new  DerivedProc1(counterHolder);
Proc* dp2 = new  DerivedProc2(counterHolder);
```

**Both benefits:**
 - Interface has been preserved.
 - Counter data has been shared (without making static, it's instance specific).

Hope this helps.